# problem positioning FILE * with fseek

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve a K&R exercise(7.7).It asks writing a program which takes filenames as arguments and searches them for a particular pattern.For the pattern matching I use the sliding window approach,that is check the first n chars for matching and then shift the "window"(I use an array) one place to the right and check again and so on until the EOF.I believe that I'm not using fseek properly.Am I doing it wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int pattern_check(FILE *);

char *pattern="dog";

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *file_name;
    int i;
    int matchings;

    for(i=1;i<argc;i++){
        file_name=strdup(argv[i]);
        fp=fopen(file_name,"r");
        if((matchings=pattern_check(fp))){
            printf("%d patterns found in %s\n",matchings,argv[i]);
        }
        fclose(fp);


    }
    system(sleep(10000));
    return 0;
}

int
pattern_check(FILE *fp)
{
    int length=strlen(pattern);
    char window[length];
    int i,c;
    int found=0;
    unsigned position=ftell(fp);


    window[length]='\0';
    while(1){
        /*load characters from file to string*/
        for(i=0;i<length;i++){
            fscanf(fp,"%c",&c);
            window[i]=c;
        }
        /*compare*/
        if(strcmp(window,pattern)==0)
            found++;
        if(feof(fp))
            break;
        /*move window one to the right*/
        fseek(fp,0,position);
        position+=1;

    }
    return found;
 }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You should change the declaration of window in pattern_check to hold another char: char window[length +1];. Otherwise, window[length] = 0; won't work correctly.

Comment: You are using feof incorrectly.  If your file has length zero, you will call scanf length times putting garbage into window, and then strcmp the garbage.  You need to check the return value of scanf to decide when to stop reading the file.  (Better yet, use fgetc instead of scanf).  You cannot use feof or ferror until after a read call has indicated an error or end of file.  The purpose of feof is to determine if an fread returning zero means "no more data" or "error".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fseek (fp, 0, position);
```

is certainly wrong, the arguments to `fseek` should be:

- the file handle.
- the position.
- the "whence" (from where the position is calculated).

In other words, it should be:

```
fseek (fp, position, SEEK_SET);
```

And, as an aside, you should generally always check the return code from functions which can fail, even if you don't think it will happen. And you may want to make `position` a `long int` as per the current standard. It probably won't make any appreciable difference for small files but you will get into trouble once you start handling files that are larger than your normal integers can handle.

Comment: You won't believe how much time I spent debugging this. I think I have mastered completely the tracking of cursor position, sizes of types, and everything involved. All came down to a few parameters in switched order. Welcome to the coding

Answer (score 2):

Arguments to fseek() are backwards?